# hibernate: entity has 2 ManyToOne foreign keys to 2 different tables doesn't work

Tags: hibernate, foreign-keys

Below is part of my `Score` Entity.
The attribute `student` links to table `student`,and attribute `exam` links to table `exam`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "score")
public class Score implements Serializable {
    private Student student;
    private Exam exam;
    private int score;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="sid")  
    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }
    public void setStudent(Student student) {
        this.student=student;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="eid")  
    public Exam getExam() { return exam;}

    public void setExam(Exam exam) {
        this.exam = exam;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "score")
    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }
}
```

And the table `Score` has attribute `sid`,`eid`,`score`.

I used a factory to create sessionfactory

```
public class ConfigureFactory {
    private static Configuration config;
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public static Configuration getConfiguration(){
        if(config==null){
            config = new Configuration().configure();
            config.addAnnotatedClass(Exam.class);
            config.addAnnotatedClass(Score.class);
            config.addAnnotatedClass(Course.class);
            config.addAnnotatedClass(Teacher.class);
            config.addAnnotatedClass(SelectC.class);
            config.addAnnotatedClass(Student.class);
            config.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);
        }
        return config;
    }
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
        if(sessionFactory==null){
            getConfiguration();
            sessionFactory=config.buildSessionFactory();
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    public static void closeSessionFactory(){
        if(sessionFactory!=null){
            sessionFactory.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Even though I just do nothing about the database,like codes below,it still throws an error.

```
ServiceRegistry  serviceRegistry =new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).build();
SessionFactory sf = config.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry); 
Session sess = sf.openSession();  
sess.close();  
sf.close();
```

[the error message in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pe5IL.png)
And I'm sure that there's nothing about the configuration,because I have another entity with one foreign key,and I succeeded getting data from database using it.
So what's wrong?...

Comment: can you show your sessionfactory properties and also post full stack trace?

Comment: Not sure it's related (given the strange name of the table), but your entity is not a valid entity: it doesn't have an ID. Turn on SQL logging to see what SQL is generated. Or use your debugger.

Comment: @JBNizet I said it's `part` of my entity~ so I didn't show the ID,it actually has one.  But thanks for the advice~ :-)

Comment: @MaciejKowalski sessionfactory added! Sorry didn't understand what do you mean by `full stack trace`